No disk displayed while installing Ubuntu 24 in HP Pavilion 15
I'm trying to install Ubuntu in my HP Pavilion 15. Disk setup options are not displaying in the Disk setup stage of the Ubuntu installer.


What version of Ubuntu? Many versions of pavilion 15, so you may need newer Ubuntu or 24.04.1. HP Pavilion desktop Desktop TP01-2XX needs acpi=off
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2479919 HP Pavilion 15t touch (15t cs-200) totally remove optane card
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2471365 HP Zbook 15 NVRAM locked, install issues multiple settings
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2482555
